# Untainting an exim4 configuration when upgrading to Debian 11

Tags: debian, configuration, email, exim

I'm aware that this question has been asked a few times before, but I've been unable to work the solutions to other people's problems into my own exim configuration successfully. I end up with a Tainted Filename on the DKIM key, or I mangle it in such a way that delivery fails. My DKIM setup is as follows:

```
DKIM_SELECTOR    = ${lookup{$dkim_domain}lsearch{CONFDIR/dkim_selectors.txt}}
DKIM_FILE        = CONFDIR/dkim-$sender_address_domain.DKIM_SELECTOR.key
DKIM_PRIVATE_KEY = ${if exists{DKIM_FILE}{DKIM_FILE}{0}}
```

(Where dkim_selectors.txt is a file containing domain name to selector mappings. There are two.)

and further down, you get:

```
  remote_smtp:
    driver           = smtp
    dkim_domain      = ${sender_address_domain}
    dkim_selector    = DKIM_SELECTOR
    dkim_private_key = DKIM_PRIVATE_KEY
```

I am not a complete novice with exim, but the old configuration Just Works and hasn't been changed in many, many years so I'm extremely rusty. I'd rather not have to set allow_insecure_tainted_data  and would appreciate any help greatly. We're still on buster and I'm testing this by using buster-backports to upgrade exim4.

How can I fix this and get off buster, hopefully before next June?